# Python Nosetests Import Error

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, module, nosetests

I am trying to run my automated tests on Python, and I keep running into an import error. My Directory Hierarchy is as follows:

```
TestingPractice
  - bin
  - README.txt
  - setup.py
  - TestingPractice
      - __init__.py
      - main.py
  - tests
      - __init__.py
      - test_main.py
```

Now when I cd to the top TestingPractice, and run nosetests, I get that my method created in main.py is undeclared, even when importing TestingPractice.main

main.py:

```
def total_hours(hours):
    sum = 0
    for hour in hours:
        sum += hour
    return sum
```

test_main.py:

```
# Test the hour computation. 
from nose.tools import *
import TestingPractice.main

def test_hours():
    to_test = [8,8,7,8] # 31
    assert_equal(total_hours(to_test), 31)
```

when running nosetests:

```
/Documents/Developer/Python/TestingPractice/tests/test_main.py", line 7, in test_hours
    assert_equal(total_hours(to_test), 31)
NameError: global name 'total_hours' is not defined
```

I have tried many different paths for the import, even the relative importing (which caused the relative importing error) and also tried export PYTHONPATH=. to no avail.

Comment: There is usually no need to have an `__init__.py` in the `test` directory. `nose` (not `nose2`) will find your test_main.py even without the `__init__.py`.

Comment: consider changing `from nose.tools import *` to `from nose.tools import assert_equal`. It makes your code more readable and is generally good practice, as you have total control, what functions and variables come to your namespace.

Comment: Would this change when I have more advanced test cases though? I see your point for this example, but when i go into using more than just assert_equal would it still be bad to import *?

Comment: It is about having clear picture, where is which variable or function coming from. If you do just one `from something import *`, it is not big problem. But as soon as you do it more times, you are messing up variables from multiple imports and it is hard to say, which package/module contribute the method/variable you use. Explicit `from something import alfa, beta` let you read such information clearly, another way is `import something` and then use `something.alfa`, `something.beta` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was, for some weird reason, not telling Python how to import the function. While a little, obvious fix, I missed it.

Here it is:

in the test_main.py I had to do:

```
from TestingPractice.main import total_hours
```

Then, while in the working directory of the top TestingPractice, nosetests worked as supposed to.

Comment: Yes, this type of explicit imports are better.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do not "cd to the TestingPractice", stay at root of your project and run your tests from there.

I was in past having exactly the same problem, trying to make all test cases runnable from test directory or even better from anywhere. But such a requirements is usually a nonsense and following a rule: **run your tests from root of your project** works very well - in fact it brings clarity to all your testing code and testing and you will love it.

Comment: I was in the root of my project. There is the root folder (TestingPractice), and then the subdirectory TestingDirectory as well: following [link](http://as.ynchrono.us/2007/12/filesystem-structure-of-python-project_21.html). Posted my solution, there was something wrong with my import.

Comment: Oh, I see, that project directory and file listing in your question shows two directories named `TestingPractice` (there is no `TestingDirectory` one).
I was assuming, you are inside the deeper one, and there you might have a problem with importing from `TestingPractice` package unless you have it installed (locally or globally) as develop package.